# Retain Cycle in DetailViewController - ARC Enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am getting a retain cycle on presenting/dismissing my DetailViewController. Any help finding an opportunity for retain cycles in the code below would be greatly appreciated.

**Question:** Is there a retain cycle in the code posted below?

[image]

iOS: 6

xcode: 4.6

tested: iphone 4 device

ARC Enabled

*Edit:* added instruments photo.

### DetailViewController.h

```
@interface SRDetailViewController : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *roomTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *userScreenContainer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *opponentScreenContainer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *retryButton; 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *progressTimer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *retryTimer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottomViewContainer;


@property (strong, nonatomic) SRRoom *room;

@property (strong, nonatomic) SROpenTokVideoHandler *openTokHandler;
```

### DetailViewController.m

```
@interface SRDetailViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* kApiKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* kSessionId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* kToken;


@end

@implementation SRDetailViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configOpentTok];
    [self performGetRoomRequest];
    [self configNavBar];
    [self configNotifcations];
    [self configProgressBar];

}

-(void)configSocialSharing
{
    //check if it already exists
    for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[SRSocialSharing class]]){
            return;
        }
    }

    //add off screen
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);
    SRSocialSharing *share = [[SRSocialSharing alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:share];

    share.sharingURL = [self createUrlForSharing];
    //animate in
    frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-100, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        share.frame = frame;
    } completion:nil];
}

-(NSURL *)createUrlForSharing
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(self.room.sessionId.length-7, 6);
    NSString *shortSessionId = [self.room.sessionId substringWithRange:range];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url/invites/%@/%@?sessionId=%@",self.room.topicId, [self opposingPosition:self.room.position],shortSessionId];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
-(NSString *)opposingPosition:(NSString*)position
{
    return ([position isEqualToString:@"agree"])? @"disagree" : @"agree";
}


-(void) configOpentTok{   
    [self.openTokHandler registerUserVideoStreamContainer:self.userScreenContainer];
    self.openTokHandler.userVideoStreamConatinerName = self.room.position;

    [self.openTokHandler registerOpponentOneVideoStreamContainer:self.opponentScreenContainer];
    self.openTokHandler.opponentOneVideoStreamConatinerName = [self opposingPosition:self.room.position];

    self.openTokHandler.shouldPublish = YES;
    self.openTokHandler.isObserving = NO;
}

-(void)configNavBar
{

    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"backButton"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 47, 32)];
    [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressBackButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *navBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:navBackButton];

    self.title = [self.room.position stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)
                                                   withString:[[self.room.position  substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];
}

-(void)pressBackButton{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    [self manageSafeClose];
    double delayInSeconds = 3;
    //[self updateStatusLabel:@"Disconnecting" withColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    });
}

-(void)configNotifcations
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(recieveNotifications:)
                                                 name:kSROpenTokVideoHandlerNotifcations
                                               object:nil
     ];
}

-(void)recieveNotifications:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:kSROpenTokVideoHandlerNotifcations]){
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSNumber *message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"message"];
        [self statusMessage: message];
    }
}

-(void)statusMessage:(NSNumber*)message{

        NSString *result = nil;

        switch([message intValue]) {
            case 0:
                result = @"Disconnected";
                break;
            case 1:
                result = @"Connecting...";
                [self startRetryTimer];
                break;
            case 2:
                result = @"Publishing Your Video...";
                break;
            case 3:
                result = @"Searching for Idiots...";
                break;
            case 4:
                result = @"Start!";
                [self startProgressBar];
                [self stopTimer:self.retryTimer];
                break;
            case 5:
                [self stopTimer:self.progressTimer];
                result = @"Stopped!";
                break;
            case 6:
                [self stopTimer:self.progressTimer];
                result = @"Disconnecting...";
                break;
            case 7:
                result = @"Opponent failed to join. Retrying...";
                [self performSelector:@selector(retry) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
                break;
            default:
                result = @"Retry";
        }

    [self updateStatusLabel:result withColor:[self statusLabelColorPicker:message] animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"STATUS LABEL UPDATE: %@", message);

}

-(UIColor*)statusLabelColorPicker:(NSString *)Message{
    return [UIColor whiteColor];
}

-(void)performGetRoomRequest{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:weakSelf.room
                                          path:nil
                                    parameters:nil
        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
            weakSelf.openTokHandler.kToken = weakSelf.room.token;
            weakSelf.openTokHandler.kSessionId = weakSelf.room.sessionId;
            weakSelf.roomTitle.text = weakSelf.room.title;
            weakSelf.navigationController.title = weakSelf.room.position;
            [weakSelf configSocialSharing];
            [weakSelf.openTokHandler doConnectToRoomWithSession];
        }failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

    }];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    self.room = nil;
}

-(void)manageSafeClose{
    [self stopTimer:self.retryTimer];
    [self stopTimer:self.progressTimer];
    [self.openTokHandler safetlyCloseSession];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
    self.openTokHandler = nil;
    self.title = nil;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.kApiKey = nil;
    self.kSessionId= nil;
    self.kToken= nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self doCloseRoom];
}

-(void)doCloseRoom
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] deleteObject:weakSelf.room
                                             path:nil
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
                                              //NSLog(@"Mapping result %@", mappingResult);
                                          }
                                          failure:nil
     ];
}

-(void)startRetryTimer
{
    NSLog(@"Timer Started");
    self.retryTimer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(60*5)
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(retry)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];
}

-(void)retry
{
    [self doCloseRoom];
    [self performSelector:@selector(performGetRoomRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
}

#pragma mark - label
- (void)updateStatusLabel:(NSString *) message withColor:(UIColor*) color animated:(bool) animated
{
    self.statusLabel.text = message;
    if (animated) {
        [self fadeOutFadeInAnimation:self.statusLabel andColor:color];
    } else{
        [SRAnimationHelper stopAnimations:self.statusLabel];
    }

}

- (void)fadeOutFadeInAnimation:(UILabel *)label andColor:(UIColor*)color
{

    //add animation
    [label.layer addAnimation:[SRAnimationHelper fadeOfRoomStatusLabel] forKey:nil];

    //change label color
    label.textColor = color;
}




#pragma mark - Progress Bar
-(void)configProgressBar
{
    self.progressBar.progressTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}

-(void)startProgressBar
{
    self.progressBar.hidden = NO;
    self.progressBar.progress = 0;
    self.progressTimer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(changeProgressValue)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
}

-(void)stopTimer: (NSTimer*)timer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}

- (void)changeProgressValue
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        float progressValue         = self.progressBar.progress;
        progressValue               += .00834;
        if (progressValue > .99)
        {
            progressValue = 1;
            [self stopTimer:self.progressTimer];
            return;
        }

        NSString* time =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", 60 - ceil(progressValue*60)];
        NSLog(@"Progress Value %f Time %@", progressValue, time);


        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time Left: %@",  time];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            self.progressBar.progress      = progressValue;
            [self updateStatusLabel:message withColor:[UIColor whiteColor] animated:NO];

        });
    });


}

@end
```

Comment: Use Instruments with allocations. Then you can look at the history of what retains/releases the view controller.

Comment: `NSTimer`s created with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats` take a strong reference to their target until the timer is invalidated.  I suspect that one of your timers isn't being invalidated.

Comment: I was also looking at the timers as the likely problem, but as long as that `manageSafeClose` method is always being called they would both appear to be getting invalidated. However `timer = nil` isn't doing anything.

Comment: Good idea, but the timers are invalidated in `manageSafeClose` which gets called before dismissing the VC.

Comment: I've uploaded a photo of the instruments allocations. From below: " I'm not brand new to profiler, but I'm not sure what is going on here. It looks like a 1.31mb object is allocated and an event triggers a GCD dispatch block that never gets released?"

Answer (score 1):

With the possible exception of the timer retention mentioned above, there are no retain cycles within the posted code. I didn't trace the logic of the timers, but it's very easy to debug.

As an added note, that is some of the best code as I've seen for avoiding common mistakes. You should be commended for doing great work.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the compliment. I've uploaded a photo of the profiler output. I'm not brand new to profiler, but I'm not sure what is going on here. It looks like a 1.31mb object is allocated and an event triggers a GCD dispatch block that never gets released?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have retain cycle with timers:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *retryTimer;

self.retryTimer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(60*5)
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(retry)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];
```

You need to set `self.retryTimer = nil` at some point    or    invalidate    the    timer. This   is weirdly    written    (`timer`    is    just    a    local    variable):

```
-(void)stopTimer: (NSTimer*)timer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

On    second    thought, `invalidate`    should    break    the    retain    cycle.    Although    are    you    certain    you're    calling    this    method?

On third thought, you **might have accidentally created several timers** - each `[self startRetryTimer]` gives you a new one. If that happens, you'll invalidate the last one, and the rest will stay in stopped state. That could be your problem.